# using selection in graph api with ids and fields to together

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In the facebook doc's they wrote :

---

"By default, most object properties are returned when you make a query. You can choose the fields (or connections) you want returned with the "fields" query parameter. For example, this URL will only return the id, name, and picture of Ben: https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?fields=id,name,picture

You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in the same response."

---

Is there way to use "?fields" and "?ids" together ?

meaning, getting 5 specific posts ids with 2-3 fields only , in one request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can do something like this:

```
&ids=<some_friends_id>,<some_other_friends_id>&fields=id,name,email,cover
```

The problem is that it returns a large "metadata" object as well - I haven't figured out how to avoid that - which will waste bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively it appears you can use batch requests as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

For instance the example URL provided:

```
https://graph.facebook.com?access_token=XXX&batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"me/feed","body":"message=Test status update&link=https://developers.facebook.com/"},{ "method":"GET","relative_url":"me/feed?limit=1"}]'
```

Or broken down:

```
https://graph.facebook.com?
    access_token=XXX&
    batch=[
        {
            "method":"POST",
            "relative_url":"me/feed",
            "body":"message=Test status update&link=https://developers.facebook.com/"
        },{
            "method":"GET",
            "relative_url":"me/feed?limit=1"
        }
    ]
```

I am only just experimenting with this myself, however my initial findings suggest you are forced to submit via POST, which I suppose makes sense, but it's also a little fiddly for testing queries from the address bar, and is not compatible with the Graph API Explorer.